# Silverlight navigation example - grouping gui controls in another assembly

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml

I created a Silverlight Navigation application.
My MainPage XAML contains the basic navigation information:

```
  <navigation:Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Style="{StaticResource ContentFrameStyle}"  
                          Source="/About" Navigated="ContentFrame_Navigated" NavigationFailed="ContentFrame_NavigationFailed">
    <navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
      <uriMapper:UriMapper>
                    <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="" MappedUri="/Views/About.xaml"/>
                    <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/{pageName}" MappedUri="/Views/{pageName}.xaml"/>
      </uriMapper:UriMapper>
    </navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
  </navigation:Frame>
```

Now I don't like the fact that the Views (Controls) are in the same assembly and I want to give the project a bit more structure and move all the Views (Controls) in a separate assembly (e.g. Gui_Layer).

Now what are steps to be taken to make the MainPage aware that the About page (for example) has moved from the current assembly to another assembly ?

I want the navigation to look for controls not in "currentAssembly/Views/" but in "Gui_Layer/Views".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In Silverlight 4 you can use a custom content loader that you can enable multi assembly view loading. The interface is `INavigationContentLoader`.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dphill/archive/tags/helix/

http://www.davidpoll.com/2009/11/30/opening-up-silverlight-4-navigation-introduction-to-inavigationcontentloader/